# Why the label of http request is repeating or duplicating in load testing results in jmeter on non-gui mode

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests, load-testing

Recored and ran the script in non-gui mode in jmeter..in the aggregate result http request label is getting duplicated more than 10 times for every http request

Comment: Please show us some code

Comment: Stuck with the 10 reputations in stackoverflow to upload screenshots

Comment: can you add a link to imgur for example ?

Comment: http://imgur.com/gallery/G0yI14V

Answer (score 0):

Seems like naming policy is applied in you test plan,

You can add a `subresults.disable_renaming=true` property in jmeter.properties file. You can find this in JMETER_HOME/bin directory.

Refer below blog for more info:-
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-5.1/

Section:-
SubResult Naming Policy:

If that is not the case, then make sure there is no variable/increment-er in the HTTP Sampler label.

Hope this helps.